# Output is blank after a for loop

Tags: python

I'm a beginner of Python, and I'd like to compare two files. Here is my idea: compare two files line by line, and write them to a third file with the difference in comparison. Then I'd like to make the output more clear that I compare the line number of each file first, but what I found is that after for loop, the third file which is the result one is blank. And it's ok if I delete for loop for the two file. Here is the script:

```
import difflib
import sys
with open('file1','r') as file1:
  with open ('file2','r') as file2:
    line_num1=sum(1 for line in file1)
    line_num2=sum(1 for line in file2)
    diffInstance = difflib.Differ()
    diffList = list(diffInstance.compare(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines()))
  with open ('result', 'w') as result:
    for i,line in enumerate(diffList):
      result.write(line)
    if line_num1 == line_num2:
      if line.startswith('+'):
         sys.stdout.write('Current-Line: {}, text: {}'.format(i-1,line))
      elif line.startswith('-'):
         sys.stdout.write('Previous-Line: {}, text: {}'.format(i+1,line))                     
    elif line_num1 > line_num2:
      x = line_num1-line_num2
    elif line_num1<line_num2:
      y = line_num2-line_num1
```

Comment: Building useful diffs of XML files is a subject on which there's actually been some amount of academic publication. You might start with http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2554893, or http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~norm/papers/ssdbm08.pdf (though the latter surveys how tools work only in the context of some fairly specialized datasets). If your goal is merely determining equality as opposed to identifying changes, by contrast, `difflib` is extremely heavyweight (running a much more CPU- and memory-intensive algorithm than necessary); I'd suggest comparing SAX-style event streams to get a fast yes/no.

Comment: thanks, but I'm wondering why the script not working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charles Duffy's comment is very useful. However, your output is blank because of these lines, as they try to read the contents of the file twice:

```
line_num1=sum(1 for line in xmlfile1)
line_num2=sum(1 for line in xmlfile2)

diffList = list(diffInstance.compare(xmlfile1.readlines(), xmlfile2.readlines()))
```

To calculate `line_num1` you are reading every line in `xmlfile1`, which means the file object stored in `xmlfile1` is left referring to the end of the file. Then you try and read from it again with `xmlfile1.readlines()`, but `xmlfile1` has no more lines to read, as it's pointing to the end of the file.

Keeping as much of your existing code as possible, the method to call is `seek()` which we can instruct to go back to the start of the file with a `0`:

```
line_num1=sum(1 for line in xmlfile1)
line_num2=sum(1 for line in xmlfile2)
xmlfile1.seek(0)
xmlfile2.seek(0)
diffList = list(diffInstance.compare(xmlfile1.readlines(), xmlfile2.readlines()))
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, it resolved my problem :)